# Every 2nd and 3rd and 4th and 5th and so on

Tags: django, django-templates

I am skipping first item and add 2 items in one  Tag. This divisibleby does not work for me.

```
<div class=container>
  <div class=row>
       skip news 1
      <div class=col-md-6>news2</div>
      <div class=col-md-6>news3</div>
  </div>

  <div class=row>
      <div class=col-md-6>news4</div>
      <div class=col-md-6>news5</div>
  </div>

 ....
</div>
```

Comment: please explain more clearly.

Comment: skip news1 object. and group 2 news objects in 1 row tag. i don't know how else i can explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mixture of conditions to accomplish this:

```
<div class=container>
    {% for news in news_list %}
    {% if forloop.counter > 1 %}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}
            {% if forloop.counter > 2 %}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
    <div class=col-md-6>{{ news }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. except last endif should be before endfor. Because i want to skip first news item.